# How does static object is calling a Private constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, static, initialization

I want to ask that how does static object is calling a Private constructor ?
  Here is the code which i used :

```
class GlobalClass
{
 int m_value;
 GlobalClass() 
  {
    cout << "in Cons" << endl;
  };
 static GlobalClass obj;
};

GlobalClass GlobalClass::obj;
```

OUTPUT - in cons

Answer (score 0):

This particular static object is a member of its class and so has access to the private members. Other objects of the same class, static or otherwise, wouldn't have such privilege and cannot be declared.